# Nested quantifier workaround?

Tags: c#, regex

I have an issue that I can't seem to find a solution for it. I'm using Regex.IsMatch to check if an input matches what's expected. If an input contains `**`, `++`, it complains. For example, I would like to save `"Message **"` as an accepted value, but I keep getting an ArgumentException saying: `"Nested quantifier *"` whenever I try to call Regex.IsMatch on it. Is there any way to workaround this?

```
public bool ResponseMatch(string responseText)
{
   return Regex.IsMatch(responseText, regexPatternString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to match `Message **` as a literal value? In this case, call `Regex.Escape`:

```
Regex.Escape("Message **") == "Message\ \*\*"
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var valueToMatch = "Message **";
var matches = Regex.IsMatch(input, Regex.Escape(valueToMatch));
```

However, if you're just using literal values and not any regex features, you might be better off using `string.Contains`.

Answer (score 1):

`"Message *"` as a regex means "match any string that has the characters m e s s a g e in that order, then match zero or more spaces".

`Regex.IsMatch` takes two inputs - the regex to see if it is matched, and the string to run the regex on. Seems you've got the two confused.

If you're trying to legitmately use `"Message **"` as a regex, you probably mean to escape the `"**"`. If you only need to escape it in handpicked strings, then fix the string to be, say, `@"Message \*\*"`. If you need to fix any number of regex inputs, then run the `Regex.Escape` over the string first.  `@"Message \*\*" == Regex.Escape("Message **")`